# Why does lrtest() not match anova(test="LRT")

Tags: r, anova, likelihood-ratio

I was looking for ways to do a likelihood ratio test in R to compare model fits. I first coded it myself, then found both the default `anova()` function and also `lrtest()` in the `lmtest` package. When I checked, though, `anova()` always produces a slightly different p-value from the other two even though the 'test' parameter is set to "LRT". Is `anova()` actually performing some subtly different test, or am I not understanding something?

Platform: R 3.2.0 running on Linux Mint 17, `lmtest` version 0.9-33

Sample code:

```
set.seed(1) # Reproducibility
n=1000
y = runif(n, min=-1, max=1)
a = factor(sample(1:5, size=n, replace=T))
b = runif(n)

# Make y dependent on the other two variables
y = y + b * 0.1 + ifelse(a==1, 0.25, 0)
mydata = data.frame(y,a,b)

# Models
base = lm(y ~ a, data=mydata)
full = lm(y ~ a + b, data=mydata)

# Anova
anova(base, full, test="LRT")

# lrtest
library(lmtest)
lrtest(base, full)

# Homebrew log-likelihood test
like.diff = logLik(full) - logLik(base)
df.diff = base$df.residual - full$df.residual
pchisq(as.numeric(like.diff) * 2, df=df.diff, lower.tail=F)
```

When I run it, `anova()` gives a p-value of 0.6071, whereas the other two give 0.60599. A small difference, but consistent, and too big to be imprecision in how floating point numbers are stored. Can someone explain why `anova()` gives a different answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The test statistics is derived differently. `anova.lmlist` uses the scaled difference of the residual sum of squares:

```
anova(base, full, test="LRT")
#  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq Pr(>Chi)
#1    995 330.29                      
#2    994 330.20  1   0.08786   0.6071

vals <- (sum(residuals(base)^2) - sum(residuals(full)^2))/sum(residuals(full)^2) * full$df.residual 
pchisq(vals, df.diff, lower.tail = FALSE)
#[1] 0.6070549
```

Answer (score 26):

As mentioned in the previous answer, the difference comes down to a difference in scaling, i.e., different estimators for the standard deviation of the errors. Sources for the difference are (1) scaling by $n-k$ (the unbiased OLS estimator) vs. scaling by $n$ (the biased ML estimator), and (2) using the estimator under the null hypothesis or alternative.

The likelihood ratio test implemented in `lrtest()` uses the ML estimator for each model separately while `anova(..., test = "LRT")` uses the OLS estimator under the alternative.

```
sd_ols <- function(object) sqrt(sum(residuals(object)^2)/df.residual(object))
sd_mle <- function(object) sqrt(mean(residuals(object)^2))
```

Then the statistic that `lrtest()` computes is

```
ll <- function(object, sd) sum(dnorm(model.response(model.frame(object)),
  mean = fitted(object), sd = sd, log = TRUE))
-2 * (ll(base, sd_mle(base)) - ll(full, sd_mle(full)))
## [1] 0.266047
```

`anova(..., test = "LRT")` on the other hand uses

```
-2 * (ll(base, sd_ols(full)) - ll(full, sd_ols(full)))
## [1] 0.2644859
```

Under the null hypothesis both are asymptotically equivalent, of course, but in finite samples there is a small difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, can we say that one variant is better than the other? Can I use the anova-test without concerns?

Comment: I don't know any theoretical results concerning this question but I wouldn't be surprised if the OLS variant performs slightly better in small samples with Gaussian errors.  But already in moderately large samples the differences should be negligible.